# Is there any rules for UK phone number and post code validation in jquery-validation-1.15.0

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I am using jquery-validation-1.15.0. I want to validate UK Phone number and postcode. Is it possible to validate with this plugin? I saw a rule for phoneUS. Please help. 
Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jQuery validator](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/)

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod('phoneUK', function(phone_number, element) {
  return this.optional(element) || phone_number.length > 9 &&
  phone_number.match(/^(\(?(0|\+44)[1-9]{1}\d{1,4}?\)?\s?\d{3,4}\s?\d{3,4})$/);
  }, 'Please specify a valid phone number'
);
```